# how to handle postgres tid column in c++

Tags: c++, postgresql

like in int in postgres can be handle by
static_cast(static_cast<int32_t>(ntohl(*((uint32_t *) l_value))));
where l_value is is retrive value from PQgetvalue() .

similarly what would be for tid

Comment: What do you want to do with the `tid` in your code? That will determine the answer.

Comment: extract the value of tid in c++ file and store it in array of char

Comment: `PQgetvalue` should already return a string, unless you are using binary mode (which you shouldn't in this case). Storing `tid`s anywhere seems like a questionable idea.